# window.focus() does not work for parent window

Tags: javascript

In the fiddle below, window.focus(); appears to do nothing. any ideas?

For example:

```
childwindow.focus();
window.focus();
```

When the above code is run, the childwindow keeps the focus, how do I get the focus to return to the parent window?

https://jsfiddle.net/51bc33kr/9/

Comment: this ususally is disabled in browsers, otherwise each open webpage would have the option to steal the focus from an active window.

Comment: I am aware, this is for an internal web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not open the parent window, so you cannot control it. There is really nothing more to say to be honest. Only once you have opened it can you control it. An option may be to open 3 windows, leave the original one alone and have a new parent window.

See this updated Fiddle ->

http://jsfiddle.net/51bc33kr/12/

```
$("#openwindows").click(function() {
    google = window.open("https://www.google.com", "");
    yahoo = window.open("https://www.yahoo.com", "");
    parent = window.open("about:blank", "");
});

$("#focusYahoo").click(function() {
   google.focus();
   yahoo.focus(); 
});

$("#focusGoogle").click(function() {
   yahoo.focus(); 
   google.focus();
});

$("#focusHome").click(function() {
    google.focus();
    parent.focus();
});
```

---

*Note: To add to my answer above. Only a thought. I see the type of actions you want to accomplish and if this is internal, like for a company, I highly recommend a browser extension. They are easy (and FUN!) to make, and give you the control you want.*

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, and perhaps a browser extension is the right way to go. Still, doesn't it seem flawed that I can open new windows and have control over their focus, but I can't control the focus of the original window? Well, thanks for letting me know of the limitations here.

Comment: Anytime bud. Keep in mind that this is setup this way so websites cannot purposely annoy you. When making an internal app, it kinda sucks. I have ran into a lot of edge cases like this. Sometimes Chrome makes flags for things to annoy you less (like a chrome flag to ignore SSL warnings on local sites), but not often.

Comment: You can't open multiple windows with one click (anymore, at least).